# Как реализована функция GetTickCount()?

Tags: winapi

Можно ли где-то посмотреть код реализации системной функции `GetTickCount()`? Что она делает? Знаю, что извлекает системное время - интересует, насколько быстро она его извлекает.

Comment: Функция возвращает [число миллисекунд](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount) с момента запуска ОС, а не [системное время](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/system-time). И поскольку она реализована в ядре Windows, которое ни разу не OpenSource, то единственное что вы можете сделать - дизассемблировать `kernel32.dll` и посмотреть на ассемблерный код.

Comment: @zed, были ли зафиксированы случаи замеров скорости работы этой функции?

Comment: А что, долго измерить? Вопрос только, с чем сравнивать. Вы какую альтернативу рассматриваете?

Comment: @zed, дело происходит бесконечном цикле (в потоке). Например, прибавлять каждый шаг цикла "1" к некоей переменной, и потом проверять, не достигла ли она какого-то значения, но это менее наглядно ("1000 шагов цикла" - не так понятно, как "10ms").